# D3 creating a simple map from JSON data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Attempting a tutorial in D3 of creating a simple map based on JSON data. Obtained a dataset from here: https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.2010.html
(The States gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.zip one) and converted the SHP to JSON using the tool: https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/

```
var w = 500;
var h = 300;
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(d3.geoAlbersUsa())

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({width:w, height:h})

d3.json("test.json").then (function(json) {

    svg.selectAll("path").data(json.features)
    .enter().append("path").attr("d", path)
})
```

Error could be in code differences between various versions of D3, linking v6 though. Could use some help spotting the problem as all I am getting is a white screen. No errors.

Comment: The ability to set multiple attributes by passing an object to .attr() was removed in d3v4, if you use `.append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h)` you might have better luck. Also, did you convert the shapefile into json or geojson?

Comment: Looking at your code again, the size of your SVG could be a factor, using the default parameters, d3.geoAlbersUsa projects across an extent of 960x600 pixels. Your SVG covers only the north west quadrant of the projected space. This won't generate an error, just a blank screen if your feature is in any other quadrant. However if you inspect the svg, you should see a path exists, but is beyond the extent of the SVG if this is the case. Sharing your json would be the easiest way to pinpoint the issue though.